# Returning related fields with Lamba LINQ entity

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, lambda

I have seen many questions related to how you can return a limited set of fields from a single EF entity with anonymous types. My issue is about the opposite of that. I want to return values from related tables along with all of the fields in my entity table:

```
IQueryable<EntityModels.TBLEFFORT> query = db.TBLEFFORT.AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(a => a.EFFDELETE == "0");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sGuid))
{
   query = query.Where(a => a.TBLEFFORTLINK.Any(b => b.TBLSHS.TBLTACT.Any(c => c.CGUID == sGuid)));
}

 query.Select(x => new EffortSearchResult()
 {
     Efguid = x.EFGUID,
     Efstatus = x.EFSTATUS
 });
```

Here my base entity is TBLEFFORT and i query directly against it on the EFFDELETE field and then i query against it with a related table TBLSHS.
However, in my anon return object i only have fields from TBLEFFORT (EFGUID and EFSTATUS). How can i include fields from the related TBLSHS entity in my anonymous return object?
The related tables are lookups so they will be 1:1. I'm not looking to return complex sets based on a FK field in TBLEFFORT

Comment: There's no `SELECT *`. You have to name each individual column in the returned type.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. you just extend out in your anon type and dig for what you need from the related tables:

```
Shguid = x.TBLEFFORTLINK.Select(b => b.TBLSHS.SOMEFIELD).FirstOrDefault(),
```